# Retrieve data from page using specific template (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I'm creating a portfolio which needs to display and thumbnail, title and link to all other portfolio pages using a specific template.

This is what I have so far, which manages to retrieve the page title and the featured image just fine. I'm struggling to retrieve the link to that page as `the_permalink()` just returns the link of the page you're currently on.

```
<?php foreach ( $builtins as $page ) : ?>
            <div class="fw-col-xs-6 fw-col-md-3  remove-column-padding ">
                <div class="casestudy">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $page->ID ) ): ?>
                        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
                        <div class="block" style="background: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
                            <h3>
                                <a href="<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_permalink', $page->post_permalink, $page->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ); ?>
                                    <span></span>
                                </a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: $builtins can you show me the print_r result print_r($builtins);

Comment: print_r outside from loop

Comment: Thanks for the response @JunaidAhmed, it's a long one http://www.codeshare.io/4tQN6

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated, still stuck on this one.

Comment: codeshare.io/4tQN6 not working

Comment: codeshare.io/4tQN6  not working Now @Lee

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Junaid,

I figured out the answer, `get_permalink($page->ID);` did the trick!